# DrawerLayout - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm getting an error stating The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. I'm not sure exactly why this is happening - I belive I have formatted everything correctly.

### XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout><com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<com.idg.omv.ui.widget.VideosListView
    android:id="@+id/videosListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selstation_up_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/selstation_up_btn" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout><android.support.v4.widget.Drawer

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: just look at your xml you can clearly see that some of your tags do not have a matching end tag

Answer (score 1):

`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` is Your `Outer Most Parent`, so you need to close at end of the file only , All your `SubViews` must be placed `within` your `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` only.

Try This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />



<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<com.idg.omv.ui.widget.VideosListView
    android:id="@+id/videosListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selstation_up_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/selstation_up_btn" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I added it  - I'm still getting the same error

Comment: The red X is on the line: </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout><com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView

Comment: @user3063132 you should format your xml better, its a jumbled pile of garbage